# Using local variables outside their functions

Tags: python, function

I understand that functions are useful for code which will be used multiple times so I tried creating a function to save myself time and make my code look neater. The function I had looks like this:

```
def drawCard():
    drawnCard = random.choice(cardDeck)
    adPos = cardDeck.index(drawnCard)
    drawnCardValue = cardValues[adPos]
```

However, I am not sure how to return these variables as they are local(?). Therefore, I can not use these variables outside the function. I am just wondering if someone could help edit this function in a way where I could use the drawnCard and drawnCardValue variables outside the function?

Comment: [`return`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use `return`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement):

```
def drawCard():
    drawnCard = random.choice(cardDeck)
    adPos = cardDeck.index(drawnCard)
    drawnCardValue = cardValues[adPos]
    return drawnCard, drawnCardValue

drawnCard, drawnCardValue = drawnCard()
```

Note, you could also write `drawCard` this way:

```
def drawCard():
    adPos = random.randrange(len(cardDeck))
    drawnCard = cardDeck[adPos]
    drawnCardValue = cardValues[adPos]
    return drawnCard, drawnCardValue
```

These two functions behave differently if `cardDeck` contains duplicates, however. `cardDeck.index` would always return the *first* index, so `drawnCardValue` would always correspond to the first item which is a duplicate. It would never return the second value (which in theory could be different.)

If you use `adPos = random.randrange(len(cardDeck))` then every item in `cardValue` has an equal chance of being selected -- assuming `len(cardValue) == len(cardDeck)`.